# How to use Docker-compose and Connecting a PHP:Apache Container and MSSQL Container

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have just started to learn PHP and MSSQL and set up both environments in docker using docker-compose. For the most part its going great as I have gotten pages created in PHP and displayed on the web while being able to create a database in azure data studio. The issue is I am trying to link my php:apache container with my MSSQ: container and be able to use PHP to display the database on the web or manipulate the database with PHP code on the web. I have done lots of searching and I can seem to figure out a way to do this. I even with a last ditch effort tried to set up PHP, the PHP driver and Apache on the MSSQL server Ubuntu container but I could only get them connected by the command line not the web. So I was wondering what code do I need to write in PHP to connect the two and what do I need to install to make the php:apache and MSSQL containers work together? Below is my docker-compose.yaml for reference. Also my file setup has the docker-compose.yaml at the root with the build: directories where all their files go. Hopefully that's some helpful info and sorry for being a beginner and not knowing exactly what info to provide to help resolve my issue? Thank you all who tries to help out in advance.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
        homepage:
             build: ./homepage
             volumes: 
             - ./homepage/public-html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
             ports:
             - 5001:80
        php:
           image: php:apache
           volumes:
               - ./php:/var/www/html
           ports:
               - 5000:80
        db:
           image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest"
           volumes:
                 - ./db:/Documents
           environment:
              SA_PASSWORD: "hidden password so my password is not leaked"
              ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
           ports:
               - 1433:1433
```

Comment: You need to just use the normal DB connection code. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php. The host would `db` in your case as that is the service name

Comment: ok I did all of that set it up but i keep getting a driver issue when I run the php code. I installed the ODBC driver on the php:apache container using pecl install sqlsrv and pecl install pdo_sqlsrv and following the link the error gave me I downloaded debian driver folder but I have no clue what do with that after I downloaded it to install the drivers. Here is the error message: [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
        )
)

Comment: Are you certain want to have db part of docker container?  You didn't share purpose of db, so maybe its all good having it be ephemeral.. but in my experience the db is usually a separate thing from the website.